# Are the words "merry", "marry" and "Mary" pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

These three words sound exactly alike to me.

Example: "The merry man married Mary!"

Is there a different pronunciation between these three words? Does having an accent change the pronunciation?  Is it a personal preference on how to pronounce these words?